# GitHub Desktop: Why won't my two created branches sync their contents from the master branch to each other?

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, pull

I have setup GitGub Desktop on two computers and am testing it out. I created two branches: DESKTOP and LAPTOP to give a designated test workspace for both devices. I created a folder in each called "New Folder" and gave this folder in both branches a different empty text file. 
Quick break down of what should be seen currently:

Branch DESKTOP:

- Git repository

  - New Folder

    - New Desktop File.txt

Branch LAPTOP:

- Git repository

  - New Folder

    - New Laptop File.txt

I have merged both branches to the MASTER branch on Github.com, which shows both created empty text files in the MASTER branch "New Folder" directory.

The thing that confuses me is when I pull from the MASTER branch to either of my DESKTOP and LAPTOP branches, the file unique to both is not pulled to the other.
Essentially, I expect my branches to now look like this after pulling from MASTER:

Branch DESKTOP:

- Git repository

  - New Folder

    - New Desktop File.txt
    - New Laptop File.txt

Branch LAPTOP:

- Git repository

  - New Folder

    - New Desktop File.txt
    - New Laptop File.txt

BUT, this didn't happen. Why didn't what was merged from one branch to MASTER get pulled down to another branch that pulled from MASTER when Master contains the file from the other branch? Why didn't the file from LAPTOP get synced to my DESKTOP branch? Why didn't the file from DESKTOP get synced to my LAPTOP branch?

Comment: you'll have to pull from the master branch to get sync. when you git pull you're only pulling from your current branch.

Comment: I'm using GitHub Desktop. While current branch says one of my created branches is the current working branch, I click fetch origin to pull from the master branch, but the file from the other branch isn't synced which is what I'm trying to figure out why that is happening.

Comment: Oh, wait! Is origin actually just the origin for the branch?

Comment: Origin is a name of the remote you’re using

Comment: Is the MASTER branch the same as origin/remote? If not, is remote what I see on GitHub.com? Where can I properly view and distinguish the two?

Answer (score 0):

Origin is the remote repository (the "server", if you will, in this case your GitHub repository). As @TheWolf said: When you pull, you only pull changes of the branch you're currently on. A pull on your `LAPTOP` branch will ony apply changes from the `LAPTOP`branch on `origin` (aka the remote repository) to the `LAPTOP` branch on the repository on your laptop.

Having that said, a simple `pull` (only pulling the currently checked out branch) will never apply changes from other branches, i.e. will not apply changes from a remote `master` branch to your `LAPTOP` branch.

You do not need to use different branches for what you want to achieve: If you work directly on the `master` branch, all three `master` branches will be synced (by pushes and pulls) between your three repositories (the repository on the laptop computer, the desktop computer and the GitHub repository).

I advise further reading on git branching and git in gereral. Good sources can be found on the [Git Tag info site](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info), for example the very good [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have continued messing with this, cause I'm just trying to get a feel for how to use Git on multiple devices with this Test repository. I found out that with GitHub Desktop while on 1 of the working branches, I can select the drop down tab menu labeled "Branch" and listed in that menu is "Merge into current branch". If I selected that, I can select another branch that will then automatically compare and let me know of any changes or commits that I can merge with the current working branch. Doing so made it so that I can get both unique text files on both branches.

Comment: I advise to always use a workflow as simple as possible. As your repository and the number of contributors grows, things can get very messy if you do not have a clear and simple workflow.
If you work on a feature, you should do so on the same branch, even across mutliple devices. Many people have achieved good results with [this](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) branching model, although many different workflows are possible with git.